# NFS share shows folder name but no content

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, nfs

I created an NFS share on my Raspberry PI (running raspbian based on debian buster). I am trying to connect to it using VLC (android tv & android 6) but when I connect to it I only see a folder named "**/home/pi/Desktop/Samba**" but no content (keeps loading). The folder is also shared using smbd which works fine.

Service status:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Samba $ sudo systemctl status nfs-kernel-server

● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2020-04-02 18:43:37 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 26587 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26588 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26588 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 02 18:43:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Apr 02 18:43:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

Config:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Samba $ cat /etc/exports

# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#               to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
/home/pi/Desktop/Samba          192.168.0.0/16(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Loading config file:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Samba $ sudo exportfs -rav

exporting 192.168.0.0/16:/home/pi/Desktop/Samba
```

Share status:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Samba $ sudo exportfs -s

/home/pi/Desktop/Samba  192.168.0.0/16(rw,wdelay,root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already got this working seeing the issue was posted in April, please share the solution for others benefit.

If not try nohide option, so /etc/exports will be as below:

/home/pi/Desktop/Samba          192.168.0.0/16(rw,sync,nohide,no_subtree_check)

Check with: sudo exportfs -v

Comment: I never actually found out the problem, just used samba instead. This does seem to fix my issue thanks a ton!